# Is the following function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)$ be continuous on some connected open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Suppose $e^{f(z)}$ is holomorphic. Does it follow that $f(z)$ is holomorphic?

I personally do not see any counterexample, but I don't know how to go about proving this assertion if it is in fact true.

The motivation for this question is to see if I can slickly prove that $Log(z)$ is holomorphic on its principal branch without a brute force calculation on the usual $Log(x+iy)$ formulation (which I can do; I'm just seeing if there's some other way). I see that $e^{Log(z)}=z$, so that $\frac{d}{d(\bar{z})}e^{f(z)}=0,$ but I don't know if I can therefore conclude $\frac{d}{d(\bar{z})} Log(z)=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I can prove this when $f$ is differentiable (as a real function of two variables). Suppose $e^{f(z)}$ is holomorphic. The chain rule for the Wirtinger derivatives implies that

$$0 = \partial_{\bar{z}}(e^{f(z)}) = [(e^{z})_{z} \circ f]f_{\bar{z}} + \overbrace{[(e^{z})_{\bar{z}} \circ f]}^{0}\bar{f}_{\bar{z}} = e^{f(z)}f_{\bar{z}}$$

Since $e^{f(z)}$ never vanishes, we must have $f_{\bar{z}} = 0$, which implies that $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: Do we know that $f_{\bar{z}}$ and $\bar{f_{\bar{z}}}$ exist?

Comment: These quantities are defined in terms of the (real) partial derivatives of $f$, which is why I asserted that $f$ has to be differentiable for this argument to work.

Comment: Ah. My selective vision passed right over that line. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Under the additional condition that $U$ is *simply-connected* , I think the answer is yes:

Let $h(z)=e^{g(z)}$. Then $h(z)$ is holomorphic and non-zero in a simply-connected region,

so that $h(z)$ admits a holomorphic log $w(z):=log(h(z))$ , meaning that $e^{log(h(z))}=h(z)$. You can then show that $g(z)$

differs from $h(z)$ by a constant, so $g(z)$ is holomorphic. But I don't know how to

weaken the condition that $U$ must be simply-connected .

I don't know if this is circular, but re your proof, since $f(z)=z$ is holomorphic,

away from $0$ , in a simply-connected region -- like the standard branch, $f(z)=z$ admits

a holomorphic log, and this is then $Log(z)$, up to a constant.